# How to disable Microsoft Edge notifications in the 3 dots menu with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run automated tests on Microsoft Edge but i am encountering an issue with the notification that pops up from the browser, the notification causes the tests to fail when they look for an element in the HTML, it looks like the context of the test moved to that notification instead of the browser itself.

[Example of the notification that causes these failures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alnRe.png)

I hav tried these solutions so far but to no avail:

```
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.popups": 2
})
```

```
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
```

Comment: Are there any updates on this issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: I actually haven't tried it yet  but I will soon and let you know! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to turn off `Show feature and workflow recommendations` by configuring flags. And something like this:

```
string driverpath = @"D:\EdgeDriver\119.0.2151.58";
var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverpath);
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("user_experience_metrics", new
{
    personalization_data_consent_enabled = true
});
options.AddArgument("--disable-features=msEdgeEnableNurturingFramework");
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(service, options);
driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";
```